# Assign Unresolved Email Task to Contact(s)

Tags: apex, tasks, emailtosalesforce

Hi so I am trying to figure out if it's possible to assign unresolved tasks created by the "Email to Salesforce" feature with a batch job that runs daily. This is to fix the case where the contact is not in Salesforce by the time the email is sent to Salesforce so the auto-assign feature wouldn't work here.

What I've looked into is querying the task record where "Unresolved" is in the subject line and their isn't a whoId or task relations. What I can't seem to find is how to get the email of the Contact from the task. The email field is always blank Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
I see on the unresolved items list for a user we have this from/to field. Is it possible to query that somehow? or is Salesforce doing something special here.
[image]

Comment: The email is not included in the Description field?

Comment: @cropredy it is but it can't be filtered in a query. Most likely because it's a text area field

Comment: The batch job can query on Task.Subject and, since it is Apex, use regex methods to find the email address within Task.Description

Comment: @cropredy yea that may be what I have to do. I was hoping to be able to query this from/to field that appears in the unresolved items list. I added a screenshot of what I'm referring to.

Comment: Can you query on an EmailMessage whose `RelatedToId` is the `Task.Id` - that would get you the from/to